# Google Map Marker from SVG Sprite not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, safari

In Google Maps I am using marker Image from  svg sprite using something like :

```
new google.maps.MarkerImage("/path/to/sprite", new google.maps.Size(46, 38), new google.maps.Point(-2, -2));
```

Works good on chrome but doesn't works on safari. Found out with png sprite it works fine but with svg sprite it has a problem. Example Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FChNK/224/

Anyone has idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? It looks fine on my machine Safari v9.0.3.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: I am using svg sprite. I think that's the reason its not working. Updating the fiddle. Please check

Comment: I've got similar trouble with FF while passing single SVG marker. Might be, the SVG itself (due to drastic minification for example) can cause the problems in certain browsers.

Comment: @Kout but  its working fine if I am passing marker as a single svg.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 92 and Safari 14.1.1 . Does anyone know if this is still an issue in 2021? Because I have experienced something similar.